# Attempting to reverse tooltips on plotly.js bar chart

Tags: bar-chart, plotly, label

I am new to plotly.js. I reversed the bars in the bar chart, but the labels are currently staying in the same place. I want to replace the values that the

What I want is the labels in the jsfiddle. I want the y labels to display on the LEFT of the labels instead of the current spot at right labels and I would also like to display the x labels on the opposite side of the bar with the tooltip.

I hope this is clear. Thanks

Here is the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/aj5qepv3/

```
var data = [{
  type: 'bar',
  x: [20, 14, 23],
  y: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  orientation: 'h'
}];

var layout = {
    xaxis:{
        autorange:'reversed'
    },
    yaxis:{
      side:'right'
    }
}

Plotly.newPlot('tester', data, layout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you?

```js
var data = [{
  type: 'bar',
  x: [20, 14, 23],
  y: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  orientation: 'h'
}];

var layout = {
    xaxis:{
     autorange:'reversed'
    },
    yaxis:{
      side:'left'
    },
    xaxis:{
      side:'top'
    }
}

Plotly.newPlot('tester', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d14fo0winaifog.cloudfront.net/plotly-basic.js"></script>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```

Comment: @KelluyRoper Does this graph meet all your requirements, if not please specify what should be corrected?